# How can I set a Title on the Config Page in Joomla Component?

Tags: php, html, xml, joomla

if I add the string:

```
COM_OHANAH_CONFIGURATION="Ohanah Konfiguration"
```

to the Language File it still doesnt get changed. Where can I set this?
I looked into the Files of different Joomla Components and all just use the String in the Language file... But in this Component it just doesnt work.
The String is located in the Config page of the component.

[image]

It would be great if someone could help me with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution was to add the String into `/language/thefileineeded` and not `/administrator/language/thefileineeded`